# Assert that a collection is in the right order

Tags: c#

How do I assert in MSTest that the order of the returned collection is correct?

```
[TestMethod]
    public void when_sorting_movies_it_should_be_able_to_sort_all_movies_by_title_descending()
    {
        populateTestMovies(movie_collection);
        MovieLibrary movieLibrary = new MovieLibrary(movie_collection);
        IEnumerable<Movie> results = movieLibrary.sort_all_movies_by_title_descending();
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(theres_something_about_mary));
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(the_ring));
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(shrek));
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(pirates_of_the_carribean));
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(indiana_jones_and_the_temple_of_doom));
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(cars));
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Contains(a_bugs_life));
        Assert.AreEqual(7, results.Count());
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a hard-coded `IEnumerable<string>` with the movie titles in the expected order, pull the titles from the result collection and use `SequenceEqual` to check that they come in the same order (assuming your referred constants are `Movie` objects, and that `Movie` has a `Title` property):

```
IEnumerable<string> expected = new[] 
{ 
    theres_something_about_mary.Title, 
    the_ring.Title,
   /* and so on */ 
};
Assert.IsTrue(results.Select(m => m.Title).SequenceEqual(expected));
```

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SequenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) extension method of IEnumerable, like so:

```
Assert.IsTrue(results.SequenceEquals(new[] {"cars", "a_bugs_life"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have used the pleasant-to-read `Assert.That()` syntax introduced in [NUnit 2.4](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.4). The important point is that the `Is.EqualTo` constraint will enforce order of the parameters.

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SameOrder() // passes
    {
        IEnumerable<int> expected = new[] { 1, 9, 0, 4};
        IEnumerable<int> actual = new[] { 1, 9, 0, 4 };
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }

    [Test]
    public void WrongOrder() // fails
    {
        IEnumerable<int> expected = new[] { 1, 9, 0, 4 };
        IEnumerable<int> actual = new[] { 9, 0, 1, 4 };
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);

Answer (score -2):

You could assert on each item on the list, if you know the order to expect:

```
Assert.IsTrue(results[0]== theres_something_about_mary)
Assert.IsTrue(results[1]== the_ring)
```

Comment: IEnumerable<T> has no indexer.